# C# is it possible to add multiple values to an item.insert

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, dropdown, listitem

I have a drop down list with multiple values, I am pulling the values from a database table.  This is working fine.  I am trying to insert a new ListItem.  I can get it to add the New ListItem with a single value.  Example:

```
ListTest.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Test", "THIS"));
```

This gives the value of "THIS", but I am needing it to have a value of "This and That and Something Else".  So if "TEST" is selected it would check the table for those 3 different items.  Is this even possible?

Comment: In order to answer this, of course we would need to know what your presentation technology is.  I'm sure the answer isn't the same between WinForms, WPF, web, third-party, etc.  Please don't make us guess.

Comment: everything is coded in asp and c#, website.

Comment: Please update your question with the appropriate tags, and remember to do so right away next time

Comment: You need to decide where to define the link between the one value and the three values that it maps to.  Do you want to do it in c# code?  Or perhaps you could do it in a table?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way with an extension method.  This assumes you want to hardcode the relationship between the selected value and the values to look up.

```
public string[] GetImpliedSelectedValues(this listBox)
{
    switch case listBox.SelectedValue)
    {
        case "this_1_thru_3": 
            return new string[] {"this1", "this2", "this3"};         
            break;
        case "this_4_and_5":  
            return new string[] {"this4", "this5"};
            break;
        default:
            return new string[] {"nothing"};
    }
}
```

Then in your codebehind, just use

```
var valuesSelected = MyListBox.GetImpliedSelectedValues();
foreach (var v in valuesSelected)
{
    DoSomething(v);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

i don t uderstand your question... i'll try
you can use for example "This_That" and perform a split

Comment: This is not an answer.